# How to display image only after completion of its download to make it appear faster to the web user?

Tags: javascript, html, image, browser

As the modern web browsers support incremental rendering of the contents(including images), but it may not seem to be faster for the users in case of slow connections. So, how to make it look faster (like facebook,twitter images)while displaying images at once after its full download instead of just showing the part of the image from top to bottom while download is still in progress?

Comment: Do you mean something like [lazy loading](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_fadein.html)?

Comment: may be,but i have no idea about it. is it what is deployed by facebook? @MoshFeu

Comment: No, just a jQuery plugin. There are a lot of plugin..

Comment: thank @MoshFeu for the info. what plugin should I look for?

Comment: I posted this plugin in the first comment. http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_fadein.html

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically download images, After Browser DOM parsing.

```
document.querySelector("DOMContentLoaded", function(evt){
   //dynamic image inserting.
});
```

refer to below post :

http://developer.telerik.com/featured/lazy-loading-images-on-the-web/